# Nested if statements declaring return false for each one

Tags: php

Say I have the following code:

```
function a() {
    if ($a) {
        if ($b) {
            if ($c) {
                // do something
            }
            return FALSE
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

In this instance do I need all the return falses or will it sort of cascade to the last one if I remove both the inner ones?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this isn't production code.

Comment: Your last return statement is out of all if blocks. Thus, if you are not using any return inside these blocks then the last one will surely get executed and would be enough to use. But then, your function will always return false (which I guess may not be what is wanted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($a && $b && $c) {
    //do something
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will cascade down the list. You don't need each return false call.

Answer (score 0):

It will fall/cascade through to the last one.

But you may also need a `return true;` in your `//do something` part as the `return false;` will be called otherwise.

The function will continoue to run until one of the three things happen:

- a `return` statement is executed
- the closing `}` of the function is reached
- an uncatched Exception or (Fatal) error occurs

Answer (score 0):

It will continue on through, however, this may not be what you want, as such a return will end the function altogether and might skip something you want done.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this for a straightforward and easily understood representation:

```
function a() {
    if ($a) {
        if ($b) {
            if ($c) {
                // do something
                return TRUE; // or something other than TRUE
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; you can safely remove all "return false;" except the last one and it will still work the same.

Once it reaches the end of an if-statement it will jump out of it and continue in the previous block of code ( a block is defined by a { and }). For example, if $a is true but $b is not, it will enter the $a-block and then skip the $b-block, continuing right after it. When the $a-block has ended it will return to the previous block. See the following illustration:

```
function a() {
    if ($a) { // $a is true, enters block
        if($b) { // $b is false, skip block
            return true;
        }
        // end of $a-block reached, leave $a-block
    }
    return false; // return false and stop further execution
}
```

A cleaner way to write the above if-statements could be:

```
If ($a && $b)
    return true;
return false;
```